# What will happen if exception thrown of a particular type don't have a catch block corresponding to that exception in c++

Tags: exception

For the code given below. How will the code behave and why?

```
    // code goes here..
    try { 
         if(a==0) throw "a is 0";
    }
    catch(int a) { ; }
    a = 19;
    //code goes here.....
```

Comment: Syntax error. `try` blocks must contain at least one `catch`. But you could have tried that, haven't you?

Comment: Sorry, my question was little wrong . I have editted the question I hope you could help me now.

Comment: Actually, I know how it will behave but I wanted to know why it will behave that way.

Comment: The problem with "why" questions is that they are ambiguous. Why does it so? Because the C++ standard says so. Why is defined that way? Because it was considered the most useful/easy to implement. Why is it useful? ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are throwing a string (aka `const char*`) but you are only catching values of type `int`, the exception will not be caught and will go on unwinding the function stack until it finds a try-block willing to catch your exception or it reaches `main` and aborts your program.

That is, if your catch block does not catch the thrown exception type it is as if it was not there.